# React redux create an action that takes the state from other part of application

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

I have a react/redux application and use redux-thunk.

I have a button in one part of application that when clicked triggers an action that takes the state of some completely different part of application and sends it to backend.  When backend response arrives it should modify some application state. How can I do that?

Check the below example:

---

Part of app with button:

```
// MyModalContainer.js
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {MyModal} from './MyModal';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    orderButtonHandler: () => {...to do...}
});

const MyModalContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyModal);
export {MyModalContainer};


///////////////////////////////////
// MyModal.js
import React from 'react';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
class MyModal extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                <Something>....</Something>
                <Something2>....</Something2>
                <Button onClick={this.props.orderButtonHandler} color="primary">
                    Order
                </Button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
export {MyModal};
```

Data to be sent to backend on button click is stored in redux under:

```
state.cartData = {
     data1: ....,
     data2: ....,
     data3: ....
}
```

and is **not rendered in MyModal**.

---

One option is that I can send `state.cartData` to `MyModal` through `MyModalContainer`, and then the button will send it to the `orderButtonHandler`. But then `MyModal` will redraw any time `state.cartData` changes even if it doesn't draw anything from `state.cartData`.

Comment: can you include any code?

Comment: I was thinking about that but I think it would only bloat the question. It's more of an architectural issue.

Comment: are you familiar with the "reducer" concept that is part of the redux pattern?

Comment: @DacreDenny Sure.

Comment: if it's an architectural question, that belongs more on another stack exchange, maybe code review?

Comment: See ["Which Site?"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/129632/341145) and ["Code Review or not?"](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5778/120114)

Comment: I included relevant code.

Comment: For me, nothing will be re-render if you have no object return via mapStateToProps. So you can write `connect(null, mapDispatchToProps)(MyModal);`. 
Only the `orderButtonHandler` is present via props to allow to dispatch an action to the redux Store, which must represent the fact to add data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution that satisfies me, but if you have better solution please post, or comment below this answer.

```
// MyModalContainer.js
import {connect} from 'react-redux';
import {MyModal} from './MyModal';
import { makeOrder } from './modules/cart';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
});
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => ({
    orderButtonHandler: () => {dispatch(makeOrder());}
});

const MyModalContainer = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(MyModal);
export {MyModalContainer};
```

The makeOrder function utilizes redux-thunk with **getState**:

```
// modules/cart.js
const makeOrders = () => async (dispatch, getState) => {

    const stateOfSomeOtherPartOfApp = getState().cart; 
    // THE CRITICAL PART IS TO GET THE STATE IN THE ASYNC ACTION CREATOR 
    // AS I FOUND OUT THAT getState IS PROVIDED BY REDUX THUNK

    const orderResponse = await makeAsyncPost(stateOfSomeOtherPartOfApp);
    dispatch({type: 'orderResponseReceived', data: orderResponse});
};
```